# An inequality involing Schwarz lemma

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, roots

I have this question for an upcoming exam and I cannot wrap my head around it.
Suppose $f\colon B_1(0)\to B_1(0)$ holomorphic and $z\mapsto f(z)-f(z_0)$ has a root of order $n$ in $z_0$, where $z, z_0\in B_1(0)$. Show that
$$
\left\lvert \frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{1-\overline{f(z_0)}f(z)}\right\rvert \leq \left\lvert \frac{z-z_0}{1-\overline{z_0}z}\right\rvert^n.
$$
We managed to prove the equality without $n$, i.e. for $n=1$ but we are clueless on the general question. In this case it works as follows:
We define the function $g_w(z) = \frac{z-w}{\overline{w}z-1}$ and show that its an involution on $B_1(0)$. Then consider
$$ h_{z_0} = g_{f(z_0)}\circ f \circ g_{z_0} $$
and see that we can apply Schwarz lemma on it. This gives us
$$ |h_{z_0}(z)| \leq |z| $$
and replacing $z$ with $g_{z_0}(z)$ keeping in mind that $g_{z_0}$ is an involution yields the desired result:
$$ \left\lvert \frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{1-\overline{f(z_0)}f(z)}\right\rvert = |h_{z_0}(g_{z_0}(z))| \leq |g_{z_0}(z)| = \left\lvert \frac{z-z_0}{1-\overline{z_0}z}\right\rvert. $$

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2092501/42969 for the case $z_0 = 0$, and then prove the general case.

Comment: @MartinR Thank you, but I still have no clue. I have tried many things on paper, but it just doesn't work out with my limited experience.

Comment: Your function $h_{z_0}$ has a zero of multiplicity $n$ at the origin, so that $|h_{z_0}(z)| \leq |z|^n$ ...

Comment: of course... @MartinR Thank you so much!